# Inherited Class Factory?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm attempting to understand how to properly create an inherited class factory in C++. I'm using C++ 14 in this example.

I made a simple example to try and understand how this works:

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual std::string Sound();
};

class Dog : Animal
{
public:
    std::string Sound() {return "Woff!";};
};

class Cat : Animal
{
public:
    std::string Sound() {return "Meow!";};
};

class Snake : Animal
{
public:
    std::string Sound() {return "Ssss!";};
};

Animal GetAnimal(std::string name)
{
    if (name == "Dog")
        return Dog();
    else if (name == "Cat")
        return Cat();
    else if (name == "Snake")
        return Snake();

    return Animal();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Sound of a dog: \"" << GetAnimal("Dog").Sound() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Sound of a cat: \"" << GetAnimal("Cat").Sound() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Sound of a snake: \"" << GetAnimal("Snake").Sound() << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Where `Dog`, `Cat` and `Snake` are all inherited classes from `Animal`. I want to acquire a local instance of each animal type from the `GetAnimal` function, provided the animal name as an argument to that function.

The code above prompts the following error upon a compilation attempt for each one of the `return` lines in the `GetAnimal` function:

```
E0269   conversion to inaccessible base class "Animal" is not allowed
```

Is it not possible to assign an inherited class object to a variable of the inherited class's base type? What would be the proper way of doing something like this in C++?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Use base class pointers or references - and you need `public` inheritance. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/MefKxExM7)

Comment: You don't have an abstract baseclass, Animal should be `virtual std::string Sound() = 0`; also with a virtual destructor at least! Your GetAnimal should be std::unique_ptr<Animal> GetAnimal()`, with allocation calls like `return std::make_unique<Dog>()`. The use of new/delete is no longer recommended in C++(unless you are within a datastructure). See R.11 of the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)

Comment: 2 problems: without the public keyword in the inheritance you can not really use a base class, and if you return an Animal (not a reference or pointer) than the is object slicing which means that the subclasses are strippen away.

Comment: The immediate problem is that you need `: public Animal` for the base class to be "visible". The next problem is that `GetAnimal` will [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use base class pointers or references and also to use `public` inheritance. It's usually a good idea to make the base class destructor `virtual` too if you plan on destructing the objects through a base class pointer, which is usually what you want to do.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    virtual std::string Sound() = 0; // needs to be implemented by derived class
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    std::string Sound() override { return "Woff!"; };
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    std::string Sound() override { return "Meow!"; };
};

class Snake : public Animal {
public:
    std::string Sound() override { return "Ssss!"; };
};

std::unique_ptr<Animal> GetAnimal(std::string name) {
    if (name == "Dog")
        return std::make_unique<Dog>();
    else if (name == "Cat")
        return std::make_unique<Cat>();
    else if (name == "Snake")
        return std::make_unique<Snake>();

    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid animal");
}
```

And used like so:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << "Sound of a dog: \"" << GetAnimal("Dog")->Sound() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Sound of a cat: \"" << GetAnimal("Cat")->Sound() << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "Sound of a snake: \"" << GetAnimal("Snake")->Sound() << "\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Sound of a dog: "Woff!"
Sound of a cat: "Meow!"
Sound of a snake: "Ssss!"
```

Comment: Thank you for this informative and straightforward answer. This method works for the example I was trying to create.
To tell you the truth, I was trying to find a way to do this without the use of pointers, but it appears to be the only way to actually acquire an instance of the animal from `GetAnimal`. I'm curious however, is it possible to then acquire the value of the `unique_ptr<Animal>` as a local variable of one of the animal derived types? Or must I always use the pointers until they go out of scope?

Comment: @Runsva You're welcome. You can _move_ the `std::unique_ptr<Animal>` around. So, `auto animal = GetAnimal(....);` and then store it somewhere with `container.push_back(std::move(animal));` - or if you have a member variable in a class defined as `std::unique_ptr<Animal> m_animal;` you can assign the return from `GetAnimal()` to that member. Runtime polymorphism and pointers usually go hand in hand so I wouldn't try to avoid pointers in those cases. Just use `unique_ptr` as a wrapper and it'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Also, what does the first destructor line `virtual ~Animal() = default;` in `Animal` mean? Does this indicate that destroying `Animal` will destroy any inherited classes from that instance as well?

Comment: @Runsva Exactly! Without a `virtual` destructor, the derived classes' destructors would not get called when the object is `delete`d via the base class pointer - leading to leaks and other sorts of uncontrollable mayhem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here:

- By default, inheritance in C++ is `private`, which means that the
  base class is only visible in the derived class. Any code outside the
  derived class will not see it. So an instance of `Dog` will not
  convert to `Animal` outside of member functions of `Dog`.
- Inheritance in C++ only works through pointers or references. When
  you return an instance of `Animal` (not a pointer or a reference),
  something called slicing occurs: a new instance of `Animal` is
  created, by copying the `Animal` part of the derived class. This
  new instance is of type `Animal`, however, and virtual functions
  in it will resolve to the function in `Animal`. Which leads us to
- `Animal` has a pure virtual function, so is abstract, and cannot be
  instantiated. Your code should result in a compiler error when you
  try to return `Animal`.

To correct this, each of these points must be addressed:

- Declare the inheritance `public`.
- Return a reference or a (possibly) smart pointer. Given the fact the
  derived classes are idempotent (as they contain no data members), I'd
  probably go with returning a reference (probably `const`: in this
  case, it really doesn't make any difference, but it's a good idea to
  always return `const` references unless you intend for the caller to
  modify the object).
- You can't instantiate `Animal`, so if there is no match, you'll have
  to do something else. You could return a pointer, rather than a
  reference, and return a null pointer if there is no match for `name`,
  or you could raise an exception, or even abort (considering no match
  as an assertion failure) -- the correct solution here depends on the
  application which will be using this code. If no match is an expected
  condition, returning a pointer is probably most appropriate. This
  would be the case if, for example, `name` comes from user input.
  Alternatively, if no match is considered something exceptional (say
  because `name` comes from a file, and no match will only occur if the
  file is corrupted), an exception will allow the program to recover,
  or at least output an error message with more information. Finally,
  if `name` has been pre-vetted, and no match is a hard programming
  error, aborting may be appropriate. (But it depends on the
  application -- in critical applications, it's usual to abort, so that
  the back-up will take over, but in applications with significant user
  input, you definitely don't want to abort without given the
  application the chance to save the data.)